# Cosa significa "careghe" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel libro *Sardegna come un'infanzia* di Elio Vittorini ho letto questo brano nel quale descrive la visita a un museo a Cagliari (il corsivo è mio):

> «Dentro un Museo deserto sorvegliato da un tale che pareva occupatissimo a spolverare i vetri delle *careghe*, ho visto e ammirato gli idoletti nuraghici e una collezione di pitture catalane.»

Non capisco il significato di "carega" in questa frase: cosa spolverava il custode del museo? Ho cercato su Internet e ho trovato su [Wikizionario](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/carega) che può essere una parola del ligure o del veneto col significato di "sedia". A me però sembra che non abbia molto senso in questo contesto: il custode spolverava i vetri delle sedie? Per di più, né Vittorini né questo libro, un diario di un viaggio in Sardegna, sembrano avere niente a che vedere con le lingue ligure o veneta. Qualcuno di voi mi sa spiegare cosa significa "careghe" in questa frase?

Comment: Il brano  si riferisce ad un *custode* non ad un *vigile*. Non sono riuscito a trovare altri riferimenti di *careghe* rispetto a quelli noti  usati in alcuni dialetti di *sedie*.

Comment: L'inganno della cadrega! :D

Comment: @Josh61: Grazie mille! Ho fatto la correzione.

Comment: Io lo interpreterei come "teche", che contenevano oggetti d'arte in un museo. Non riesco a trovare niente che lo confermi però.

Comment: @writingthesis: Cos'è "l'inganno della cadrega"?

Comment: Charo: immagino che @writingthesis si riferisca a uno sketch comico di una decina di anni fa, che puoi trovare su https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9uRj9fV-i4. Può essere complicato da comprendere per uno straniero; la comicità si basa tutta su contrasti tra abitanti del nord/sud italia, al punto che alcuni potrebbero trovarlo offensivo, e ci sono molte espressioni dialettali (come per l'appunto "cadrega", sedia in Lombardia). Non sembra collegato all'uso di "careghe" nella tua domanda.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Molto divertente, anche se non capisco tutte le parole!

Comment: Abbastanza azzardato, ma potrebbero essere teche/vetrine in cui sono conservate sedie, per cui "i vetri delle careghe" starebbe per "[i vetri de] le teche delle sedie"?

Comment: "occupatissimo a spolverare i vetri delle careghe" è ironico, significa che il guardiano se ne stava seduto senza preoccuparsi del suo lavoro.

Comment: @danielefrisanco: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Grazie del tuo intervento, ma penso che non sia una vera risposta alla domanda che è sul significato di "careghe".

Comment: Grazie. Caregha è inteso come sedia, lui spolvera la sedia standoci seduto sopra.

Comment: Ma non è molto strano "i vetri delle sedie"?

Comment: Effettivamente è strano, se fosse "i vetri dAlle sedie" avrebbe più senso. In ogni caso credo sia una espressione simile a "scaldare la sedia".

Answer (score 6):

Careghe, in effetti, potrebbe significare SEDIE. Anche in Sardegna, come in Veneto e in altre regioni, ha questo significato, con alcune varianti ovviamente, come CADIRA. C'è però un altro possibile riferimento. La parola **Càriga**, non, **Carìga** significa NASO. Di solito si usa al plurale perché indica entrambe le narici "is carigasa".

Comment: In effetti, questo significato si trova in questo [dizionario](http://www.logosdictionary.org/index.php?code=5574068&from=CD) e anche qui, https://books.google.es/books?id=07RfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=c%C3%A0riga&source=bl&ots=cft6VkksQZ&sig=1dfbkTxy0owW0_SmNKdJDLAU9ao&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1CBrVdG8KYvaU6SkgMAD&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=c%C3%A0riga%20sardu&f=false e qui, http://issuu.com/polsabic/docs/vocabolario_sardo_campidanese.

Comment: In catalano, "cadira" significa proprio "sedia".

Comment: @user1514: Potrebbe riferirsi a [questo tipo di scultura](http://storiaearcheologiadellasardegna.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/i-giganti-di-monti-prama.html?m=1) o anche [questa](http://www.frru2.altervista.org/ARCH/VEP/NEO/ITA/NeI_SaMandara.jpg) nelle quali l'elemento prominente è proprio il naso?

Comment: Se si tratta di una parola di orgine sarda, potrebbe trattarsi di qualcosa menzionata dal custode.

Comment: I vetri delle càrighe sono gli occhiali... si pulisce le lenti. La cosa era tanto a portata di mano che mi è sfuggita di testa. È vero che "is carigasa" (le carighe italianizzato) sono i punti di passaggio dell'aria, come le finestre in un locale, ma analizzando a mente fredda la frase è chiarissimo che si tratta degli occhiali. Sicuro al 100%

Comment: Non capisco bene. Cosa c'entrano gli occhiali con le narici? E non è un po' strano "spolverare gli occhiali"?

Comment: Con càrighe (càrigas) o càreghe si intendono le narici, ma in senso lato anche il naso. I vetri sul naso sono le lenti degli occhiali. Spolverarle è inteso come pulirle. Non capisco perché ieri non mi sia venuto in mente subito!

Comment: Penso che a Milano si dica "cadrega" con *d* (cosí si pronuncia nella mia famiglia), ma non ho controllato.